# PostgreSQL and GRANT statement

Tags: postgresql

I have n schemas on my PostgreSQL server (V9.2) and n users (1 user per schema). I just want to assign the privileges `SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE` for `user1` to `schema1`, for `user2` to `schema2`, for `usern` to `scheman` on each table.

I can not do this with this statement :

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON SCHEMA schema 1 to user1
```

because the clause `...ON SCHEMA` works only with `CREATE` and `USAGE` privileges.

So what is the fastest way to assign all those privileges on each tables to concerned user please ? I hope the only way is not to do one `GRANT` statement per `schema.table`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the option "ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA":

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_1 to user1;
```

See the manual for more details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html

Comment: Nice ! That's was exactly what I was looking for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Although there are quite a few different solutions for this problem (including manually modifying the grant tables) I would personally suggest using a tool to make it easier.

With pgAdmin3 for example, you can simply change the rights for all objects within a schema in batch.

http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/grantwiz.html

Comment: I use pgAdmin3 but I don't know how to launch/execute this tool

Comment: You can execute it with the right mouse button on a table/database/schema/etc.